# Set the weights of decision functions through stdin in Sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

Is there a method that I can input the coefficients to the `clf` of SVC in my script, then apply `clf.score()` or `clf.predict()` function for further test?

Currently I am using `joblib.dump(clf,'file.plk')` to save all the information of a trained `clf`. But this involves the disk writing/reading. It will be helpful for me if I can just define a `clf` with two arrays representing the support vector (`clf.support_vectors_`), weights (`clf.coef_`/`clf.dual_coef_`), and bias (`clf.intercept_`) respectively.

Comment: I think the problem here is that `clf` may have other state params other than the ones you mention so you are best pickling or using joblib to guarantee repeatability with a trained `clf`. It may be possible for certain classifiers that have fewer params but not 100%. You could just try it and see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This line](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/svm/base.py#L303) calls the prediction function from libsvm. It looks like this (but please take a look at the whole function `_dense_predict`):

```
libsvm.predict(
        X, self.support_, self.support_vectors_, self.n_support_,
        self.dual_coef_, self._intercept_,
        self.probA_, self.probB_, svm_type=svm_type, kernel=kernel,
        degree=self.degree, coef0=self.coef0, gamma=self._gamma,
        cache_size=self.cache_size)
```

You can use this line and give it all the relevant information directly and will obtain a raw prediction. In order to do this, you must import the libsvm `from sklearn.svm import libsvm`. If your initial fitted classifier is called `svc`, then you can obtain all the relevant information from it by replacing all the `self` keywords with `svc` and keeping the values. If `svc._impl` gives you `"c_svc"`, then you set `svm_type=0`.

Note that at the beginning of the `_dense_predict` function you have `X = self._compute_kernel(X)`. If your data is `X`, then you need to transform it by doing `K = svc._compute_kernel(X)`, and call the `libsvm.predict` function with `K` as the first argument

**Scoring** is independent from all this. Take a look at `sklearn.metrics`, where you will find e.g. the `accuracy_score`, which is the default score in SVM.

This is of course a **somewhat suboptimal** way of doing things, but in this specific case, if is impossible (I didn't check very hard) to set coefficients, then going into the code and seeing what it does and extracting the relevant part is surely an option.

Comment: Smart approach! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this blog post](http://blog.scrapinghub.com/2014/03/26/optimizing-memory-usage-of-scikit-learn-models-using-succinct-tries/) on memory usage of *sklearn* models using succinct tries to see if it is applicable.

If the other location does not have access to the *sklearn* packages you would need to create your own score and predict functions. `clf.score()` and `clf.predict()` requires *clf* to be an *sklearn* object.

Comment: My last answer which had this comment with an upvote was deleted because I asked for clarification in my first post.  However I did not yet have the priviledge (50 points) to leave comments so I was not able to ask there, but still felt like I could contribute, so I asked the only way I could.  The mods should maybe allow new prospective answerers to leave comments if they want to avoid that problem in the future.  Anyways above is the answer that may be helpful.

Comment: Thank you again! The link is helpful. I'm still reading (probably not easy for the entry level like me though :)). I upvoted your answer again! You can leave comments to the posts now.  Besides, I found from another post saying that some of the clf parameters are only readable, and we cannot set parameters to them, sadly support vectors and weights are included.

Comment: What is your application?  Is the second location where you are hoping to run the model a PC or is it some embedded system?  I would expect there to be some way to run a pre-trained model on a reduced computing environment.